# Unity Serialized Dictionary `Index Out Of Range` after 12 items

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization, unity-game-engine, deserialization

**Update:** This is a confirmed bug from Unity and it has been filed.

I have created a generic serializable dictionary and a specific one for int:Object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;

/// <summary>
/// Is what it sounds like
/// </summary>
[System.Serializable]
public class SerializableDictionary<TKey,TValue> : Dictionary<TKey,TValue>, ISerializationCallbackReceiver 
{
  [SerializeField]
  protected List<TKey> keys = new List<TKey>();

  [SerializeField]
  protected List<TValue> values = new List<TValue>();

  //Save the dictionary to lists
  public void OnBeforeSerialize()
  {
    keys.Clear();
    values.Clear();
    foreach(KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> pair in this)
    {
        keys.Add(pair.Key);
        values.Add(pair.Value);
    }
  }

  //Load the dictionary from lists
  public void OnAfterDeserialize()
  {
    this.Clear();

    if(keys.Count != values.Count)
    {
      throw new System.Exception(string.Format("there are {0} keys and {1} values after deserialization. Make sure that both key and value types are serializable."));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<keys.Count; i++)
    {
      this.Add(keys[i], values[i]);
    }
  }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class DictionaryOfStringAndInt : SerializableDictionary<string, int> { }

[System.Serializable]
public class DictionaryOfIntAndSerializableObject : SerializableDictionary<int, ScriptableObject> 
{
}
```

However the compiler goes crazy with the error

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Enumerator[System.Int32,UnityEngine.ScriptableObject].MoveNext
>   ()

For some reason this line

`foreach(KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> pair in this)`

Throws that error but ONLY AFTER my `DictionaryOfIntAndSerializableObject` exceeds 12 objects. This baffles me completely.

Can you think of a reason why this `DictionaryOfIntAndSerializableObject` is throwing an out of range exception after 12 items?

**Update** This post has the same issue: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/serializeable-dictionary-exceptions-after-code-change.319285/

**Further Explanation**

I have a database GameObject that holds all my model (type) data. And what I am doing is I parse CSV files into `ScriptableObjects` that I store inside the database GameObject. That way my database is compiled once at runtime and I can freely access it at both runtime and in the editor. This database object is what has the `DictionaryOfIntAndSerializableObject` objects. I have one for every table (so I have one for weapons, armor, etc).

Here is the base class of all my scriptable objects (that get stored as the value in the dictionary):

```
public class M_Card : ScriptableObject

{

  public E_CardTypes cardTypeID;

  public int rankID;

  public int rarityID;

  public int qualityID;

  public int editionID;

  public Sprite sprite;

 public M_Card()
 {
    cardTypeID                  = 0;
    rankID                      = 0;
    qualityID                   = 0;
    sprite = null;
 }

}
```

And here is the code where (after parsing the a row from the CSV) I put an instance of M_Card into the dictionary:

```
 private void LoadActionCards()
 {
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> listData = CSVReader.Read("Actions");

    for (var i = 0; i < listData.Count; i++)
    {
      Dictionary<string, object> data = listData[i];

      string name = (string)data["Name"];
      M_ActionCard card = ScriptableObjectCreator.createActionCard(name);

      int cardTypeID  = (int)data["CardTypeID"];
      card.cardTypeID = (E_CardTypes)cardTypeID;

      AssignActionCardValues(card, data);

      Database.ACTION_CARD_LIST.Add(card);

      // THIS IS WHERE I MAP THE TYPEID TO THE M_CARD OBJECT
      // THIS IS WHERE THE OBJECT IS ADDED TO THE DICTIONARY
      Database.ACTION_CARD_MAP[card.ID] = card;
    }
  }
```

So right now I have 4 tables of data (weapons, helmets, armor, classes). However, if any of those tables has more than 12 items I get that error 100% on the 13th item. I am still investigating but heres how keys are added to the dictionary.

Note that the M_HelmetCard is just the same as an M_ActionCard and they are both just empty subclasses of the M_Card.

Here are some pictures to add a little more proof. In the first I have all 16 helmets. The error appears
[image]

Then here I make it so there is only 12 and the error is gone. 
[image]

Any list that reaches more than 12 errors out. The actual items don't matter (so its not like a specific 13th item is corrupted, 13 of the same items still cause this error).

Very baffled at the moment.

(I thought maybe the issue was I had a `Sprite` class that was getting serialized and was too much data, but when I got rid of it the problem persisted).

**Update** Here is a link to a sample project which has this issue (everything irrelevant removed). https://www.mediafire.com/?axxn3u823cm7c59

To produce the error:
Click the `database` object in the heirachy and click `Update Database` button.

Then just hit play and you will see the error.

Then if you want to see how its the 13th item, open the Helmets CSV file (`\Assets\Resources\ExcelData`), and remove the 13th item. Then update the database again. Then hit play. The error will be gone!

This is a major WTF :?

Comment: `However the compiler goes crazy with the error...` Do you mean you get compile time error? Or do you get this at runtime?

Comment: Looks suspicious to me... `int value = keys[Random.Range(0, keys.Count)];` especially the `Random` part...

Comment: Yea dont worry about the RandomID (its not even used atm :P).

Comment: @dotnetom I get an error both at runtime, and without the play button hit. In fact sometimes (randomly) the compiler spams that error non stop until I reload the scene. I will link in my answer to someone elses post with the same issue.

Comment: I have read here and there that Dictionary cannot be serialized in C#. Could it be a conflict with the interface? What if instead of inheriting from Dictionary, you would have a Dictionary in your class as a container?

Comment: Can you change lists names from keys and values to somthing else? I am worried it cause you are hiding the base lists.

Comment: Thanks @Joe I will do some more digging tonight and see if I can flesh out more details.

Comment: @fafase You are right you can't serialize a dictionary. Hence why I needed to make this custom class that acts as a dictionary but can be serialized.

Comment: @Aggressor i for one have not yet had time to try your new sample unfortunately....I hope soon

Comment: @Jow Blow Unity already confirmed its a bug so well just have to wait. Thanks for looking into this. Will update if/when they do.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon the same issue. It seems like Unity's serialization sometimes break the internals of the serialized dictionary so that additional values can't be added.

In my case I got rid these errors by implementing the `IDictionary` interface on the `SerializableDictionary` and delegating it's functionality to a private `Dictionary` object that is untouched by Unity's serialization.

Here is my solution generated with the kind help of Visual Studio

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    [SerializeField]
    private List<TKey> keys = new List<TKey>();

    [SerializeField]
    private List<TValue> values = new List<TValue>();

    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary).Keys;
        }
    }

    public ICollection<TValue> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary).Values;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary).Count;
        }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary).IsReadOnly;
        }
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary)[key];
        }

        set
        {
            ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary)[key] = value;
        }
    }

    public void OnBeforeSerialize()
    {
        keys.Clear();
        values.Clear();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair in this)
        {
            keys.Add(pair.Key);
            values.Add(pair.Value);
        }
    }

    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

        if (keys.Count != values.Count)
        {
            throw new System.Exception(string.Format("there are {0} keys and {1} values after deserialization. Make sure that both key and value types are serializable.", keys.Count, values.Count));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
        {
            Add(keys[i], values[i]);
        }
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary).Add(key, value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary).ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        return ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary).Remove(key);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        return ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary).TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary).Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary).Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary).Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary).Remove(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IDictionary<TKey, TValue>)dictionary).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: I came up with a different solution but thank you for sharing. I will revisit what you have here if the need arises!